# Excel: conditional formatting, check if column contains text from other sheet

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

First sheet:

```
First name  Last name       Role
Valeria     Bianchi         Admin
Evelise     Verdi           Teacher
Daniele     Rossi           Teacher
Annamaria   Neri            Admim
Anna        Gialli          Manager
Anna Bella  Proietti        Teacher
Simona      Ciaociao        Manager
Elisabetta  Lilla           Admin
```

Second sheet:

```
Email       Name
a@mail.com  Valeria Bianchi
b@mail.com  Daniele Rossi   
c@mail.com  Annamaria Neri  
d@mail.com  Anna Gialli 
e@mail.com  Simona Ciaociao
f@mail.com  Elisabetta Lilla
```

Now I have a rule for conditional formatting that colors the rows in the first sheet if Role is equal to Teacher:
`=$C2:$C200="Teacher"`. I'd like to add a second rule that colors the row of another color if Role is equal to Teacher AND in the second sheet is present its name in the Name column (only the row with `Daniele Rossi` should match this rule).

Hope it was clear.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick. You will have to fix the cell references to match your sheet.

Also make sure you have the order of the rules correctly and stop processing more rules if there is a match.

The concatenate adds first and lastname columns in first sheet
Sheet2!$a$1:$a$6 is the range for the names in the 2nd sheet

```
=AND(MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2;" ";B2);Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6;0); C2="Teacher")
```

Comment: Yep! It works! :)
One last thing: the color is applied only to the first cell of the row.. how can I apply it to the whole row? I selected the whole table in the "apply to" field.

Comment: Probably need to fix some of the column references for it to work over all columns in your table. =AND(MATCH(CONCATENATE($A2;" ";$B2);Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6;0); $C2="Teacher")

Comment: Yes!!!!!! Really last thing: how can I modify Sheet2!$A$1:$A$6; to target all the column instead of 1 to 6 rows? I tried with A:A but didn't work..

Comment: I hope you mean all the rows. In that case Sheet2!A:A should work (no $) Tip: Copy the formula to a cell (will give true/false result) and play with the excel formula bar to get it right. Then add it as a formatting rule

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `AND` operator, to reference another sheet use the `!`. Example

```
=AND(C2="Hello", OtherSheet!C4="Hi")
```

Comment: Yep, but I can't specify a fixed text (like, Hello or Hi). The formula needs to check if in column "Name" of the other sheet is present text from column "First name+Last name" in first sheet, but row per row.