# Google Docs (Spreadsheets): Conditional Formatting Referencing Other Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Google Docs (Spreadsheet) tells me that this (custom) formula is wrong.. in Excel instead works:

```
=AND(MATCH(CONCATENATE($A2;" ";$B2);Allievi!$G$1:$G$1204;0); $L2="Facilitatore di classe")
```

It just tells me it's not valid. The problem is that it seems not possible to reference other sheets (in the same doc) in conditional formatting rules..

Any workaround?
I need to keep data in different sheets.

[image]

Comment: Be careful about MATCH there, it could return `NA` if no match is found, and then the AND will fail.  If you just want to check if something exists in the list, wrap an `ISERROR` around the MATCH ...

Comment: Locale is italian.
Ditto: it works on Excel though..

Comment: I tried replacing ";" with ",".. still error.

Comment: @Ditto the MATCH comes from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28676434/1342772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the sheet and cell [indirectly](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).

`=INDIRECT("SHEETNAME!"&"CELLRANGE")`

**INCLUDE THE QUOTATION MARKS**

For your formula it should be something like

```
=AND(MATCH(CONCATENATE($A2;" ";$B2);INDIRECT("Allievi!"&"$G$1:$G$1204";0); $L2="Facilitatore di classe")
```