# AppScript: Compare values in two Google worksheets in the same document and highlight differences

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet which contains two worksheets. My goal is to have the AppScript to highlight any values that changed in red. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993416/compare-the-values-in-two-google-worksheets-in-the-same-document) on Stackoverflow but it's only comparing 1 row at a time.
I'm new to Appscript and I'm trying to change the script to ask the user what the worksheets names are and also compare the whole sheet (not just 1 row). I'm not sure why my script is not running. Here is an example [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irqPXNZ0pahWSUiKXyO4bqjnVF9eU6wNVgd86y2IWHw/edit#gid=0) if needed.

Thank you in advance.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Find Changes')
      .addItem('Click here to find Changes', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result1 = ui.prompt("Please enter 1st Sheet Name");
  var result2 = ui.prompt("Please enter 2nd Sheet Name");
  compare(result1,result2);
}


function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(result1);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(result2);
  var values1 = sheet1.getRangeList(['A1:Z1000']).getValues()[0];
  var values2 = sheet2.getRangeList(['A1:Z1000']).getValues()[0];
  
  var backgrounds = []; 
  for (var k = 0; k < values1.length; k++) {
    backgrounds.push(values1[k] == values2[k] ? 'white' : 'red');
  }
  sheet2.getRangeList('A1:Z1000').setBackgrounds([backgrounds]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your `menuItem1()`, you call `compare(result1,result2);`. But, at the function `compare`, the arguments are not used like `compare()`.
- And, even when `function compare(result1,result2) {` is used, the values `result1,result2` are PromptResponse object. Please be careful about this.
- Unfortunately, Class RangeList has no method of `getValues` and `setBackgrounds`. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function menuItem1() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result1 = ui.prompt("Please enter 1st Sheet Name");
  var result2 = ui.prompt("Please enter 2nd Sheet Name");
  compare(result1.getResponseText(),result2.getResponseText());
}

function compare(result1,result2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(result1);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(result2);
  var values1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var values2 = range2.getValues();
  var backgrounds = values1.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => c == values2[i][j] ? 'white' : 'red'));
  range2.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

- In this modification, when you run "Original" and "Copy" are put to the 1st and the 2nd prompt, respectively, the cells of "Copy" sheet are highlighted.

#### Testing:

When your provided Spreadsheet is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- From your script of `var values1 = sheet1.getRangeList(['A1:Z1000']).getValues()[0];` and `var values2 = sheet2.getRangeList(['A1:Z1000']).getValues()[0];`, I used the data range.

#### References:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> By any chance do you happen to know why I am getting Error message “TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘0’)”? pastebin.com/c6DYgvAM

How about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function menuItem1() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result1 = ui.prompt("Please enter 1st Sheet Name");
  var result2 = ui.prompt("Please enter 2nd Sheet Name");
  compare(result1.getResponseText(),result2.getResponseText());
}

function compare(result1,result2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(result1);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(result2);
  var values1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var values2 = range2.getValues();
  var maxRow = values1.length > values2.length ? values1.length : values2.length;
  var maxCol = values1[0].length > values2[0].length ? values1[0].length : values2[0].length;
  var backgrounds = [...Array(maxRow)].map((_, i) => [...Array(maxCol)].map((_, j) => {
    if (values1[i] && values1[i][j] && values2[i] && values2[i][j]) {
      return values1[i][j] == values2[i][j] ? 'white' : 'red';
    }
    return 'red'; // If you want to set "white" when values2[i][j] is empty, please use return (values2[i] && values2[i][j]) ? 'red' : 'white';
  }));
  range2.offset(0, 0, backgrounds.length, backgrounds[0].length).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: By any chance do you happen to know why I am getting Error message “TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘0’)”? https://pastebin.com/c6DYgvAM

Comment: @Ken Thank you for replying. About `By any chance do you happen to know why I am getting Error message “TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘0’)”?`, I'm worried that you might have changed your provided Spreadsheet. Because my proposed script is to your initial provided Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If you didn't change from your initial provided Spreadsheet, I apologize.

Comment: I was able to get your code working with your updated script. I also modified the script so that both sheets show red when there is a change. I forgot to ask. Would it be easy to modify the script so that it can ask the user which column is the unique identifier? And find changes based on unique identifier? 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJWPxdDClINPxntN5udvzAEUdmwN91mxZaHAnCA7v-E/edit#gid=0

Thanks.

Comment: @Ken About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Oh okay, I created a new question. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689989/appscript-compare-values-in-2-google-worksheets-in-the-same-document-and-highli